Put borders below all the rows with the last date value in a date series
I have an Excel worksheet to record daily flow of business. In the A column is the date of registration and in the other columns information about the item.
I need to put borders below the row of each last date, to visualize the individual dates better.

How do I run through every date and select the last one of each batch?
With VBA I was able to put borders around specific cells:
Range("A1").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous

I am unable to find out how to reference the specific rows of the sheet.

Conditional formatting can easily do that, just compare a value to either the prev or next cell. You state "but it did not quite do the job", what happend?

I was able to put borders on each distinict row, but I do not know how to only put the border on the last date, and not on the same dates as well.

With conditional formatting
The formula:  =IF($A2<$A3,TRUE,FALSE)
Apply to : =$A$2:$C$2000 'where C is the last column to underline, 2000 the last row
Format: Border -> Outline -> Bottom line click



It's sufficient to have =$A2<$A3 as formula, no need to use the If-function.
